# SQL Query to Count Number of Days, Excluding Holidays/Weekends

Tags: sql

I have a "workDate" field and a "receivedDate" field in table "tblExceptions."  I need to count the number of days beteen the two.  workDate always comes first - so, in effect, it's kind of like workDate is "begin date" and receivedDate is "end date".  Some exclusions make it tricky to me though:

First, I need to exclude holidays. i do have a table called "tblHolidays", with one field - holidayDate. I have holidays stored up through next year, so maybe I can incorporate that into the query?

Also, most flummoxing is that work dates can never occur on weekends, but received dates can.  So, i somehow need to exclude weekends when i'm counting, but allow for a weekend if the received date happens to fall on a saturday or sunday.  so, if the work date is June 3rd, 2011, and received date is June 11th, 2011, the count of valid days would be 7, not 9.

Any help on this is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your schema or a query demonstrating what you have tried so far so that we can try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should give you the number of days with the holidays subtracted:

```
select
  days = datediff(day, workDate, receivedDate)
  - (select count(*) from tblHolidays where holidayDate >= workDate and holidayDate < receivedDate)
from
  tblExceptions
```

Note that the date functions differ between database systems. This is based on MS SQL Server, so it may need adapting if you are using some other database.

Comment: this works great. i need to select lots of columns from the main data table, and being able to select the datediff column is very cool.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table full of dates to **include** (non-weekends, non-holidays, etc.) and you knew when the 'begin' date and the 'end' date is, then you can do something roughly like this:

```
select count(*) from tblIncludedDates where beginDateValue <= dateField and endDateValue >= dateField
```

to get the number of valid days between those dates.