# DATEDIFF between two dates, excluding specific days

Tags: sql-server

**SQL server** 
create Function to calculate the difference between 2 date one of the parameter is the days which i want to exclude from the duration ???

> Blockquote

**Example** : from 4-11-2018 to 29-11-2018 if i passed Sunday and Monday the result must exclude each Sunday and Monday the duration will be
  26 (total days)-8(count of excluded days ) =18 day

Comment: What dbms are you using where DATEDIFF takes excluded dates as a parameter and why not just subtract then number of days you want to exclude from the result of DATEDIFF? If I have misunderstood your question then please clarify it with a code example and some sample data.

Comment: Please provide code examples, but if you want a difference of the 2 dates and want to exclude some days, just get date diff and subtract the number of days you want to exclude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query to Count Number of Days, Excluding Holidays/Weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270734/sql-query-to-count-number-of-days-excluding-holidays-weekends)

Comment: how can i calculate the count of the days between 2 date for example : from 4-11-2018 to 29-11-2018 if i passes Sunday and Monday the result must exclude each Sunday and Monday the result must be = 26-8=18

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @user10477575 Please update your question instead of writing explanations in the comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give a go to below solution, not sure if this is the best solution but strongly doubt there is easy one anyway.

**Dates @from and @to are included in calculation.**

Leave some comment if need more info.

Tested on SqlServer.

```
-- declare params
declare @from datetime = '2018-09-29 00:00:00.000'
declare @to datetime = getdate()

declare @param nvarchar(150) = 'Monday Wednesday'
declare @daysToSunstract int = 0

-- find days to substract based on @param
if (@param like '%Monday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -7, @to)/7-datediff(day, -6, @from)/7)
if (@param like '%Tuesday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -6, @to)/7-datediff(day, -5, @from)/7)
if (@param like '%Wednesday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -5, @to)/7-datediff(day, -4, @from)/7)
if (@param like '%Thursday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -4, @to)/7-datediff(day, -3, @from)/7)
if (@param like '%Friday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -3, @to)/7-datediff(day, -2, @from)/7)
if (@param like '%Saturday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -2, @to)/7-datediff(day, -1, @from)/7)
if (@param like '%Sunday%')
    set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -1, @to)/7-datediff(day, 0, @from)/7)

-- final result
select datediff(day, @from, @to)+1 - @daysToSunstract as TotalDays
```

Now you need to include above logic in your Stored Procedure.

> FUNCTION option

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DAYS_BETWEEN_DATES] (@from datetime, @to datetime, @exclude NVARCHAR(150))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    declare @daysToSunstract int = 0

    -- find days to substract based on @param
    if (@exclude like '%Monday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -7, @to)/7-datediff(day, -6, @from)/7)
    if (@exclude like '%Tuesday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -6, @to)/7-datediff(day, -5, @from)/7)
    if (@exclude like '%Wednesday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -5, @to)/7-datediff(day, -4, @from)/7)
    if (@exclude like '%Thursday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -4, @to)/7-datediff(day, -3, @from)/7)
    if (@exclude like '%Friday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -3, @to)/7-datediff(day, -2, @from)/7)
    if (@exclude like '%Saturday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -2, @to)/7-datediff(day, -1, @from)/7)
    if (@exclude like '%Sunday%')
        set @daysToSunstract = @daysToSunstract + (select datediff(day, -1, @to)/7-datediff(day, 0, @from)/7)

    -- final result
    return (select datediff(day, @from, @to)+1 - @daysToSunstract as TotalDays)
END
```

Test:

```
select [dbo].[DAYS_BETWEEN_DATES]('2018-09-29', '2018-11-29', 'Monday,Friday')
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate from variables, you could use a recursive CTE to get the days in that range and their corresponding weekday.
Then count the workdays from those.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-11-04';
DECLARE @StopDate DATE = '2018-11-29';
DECLARE @WorkDays INT;

SET DATEFIRST 1; -- Monday as first weekday
DECLARE @WeekendDay1 INT = 7; -- 7: Sunday, when @@DATEFIRST = 1
DECLARE @WeekendDay2 INT = 1; -- 1: Monday, when @@DATEFIRST = 1

WITH DATES AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate dt, DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) wd
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dt), DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(DAY,1,dt)) wd
    FROM DATES
    WHERE dt < @StopDate   
)
SELECT @WorkDays = COUNT(*)
FROM DATES
WHERE wd NOT IN (@WeekendDay1, @WeekendDay2) 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 366);

SELECT @WorkDays AS WorkDays;
```

But if you have a permanent table with all dates, then you could use that instead.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Calendar
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StopDate
  AND DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) NOT IN (@WeekendDay1, @WeekendDay2);
```

If that table contains holidays then you could also use that in the criteria.